# Entity framework do case on discriminator

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Is there a way to cast inside query to subclass?

If I would be quering only single subclass I would do

```
auctions.OfType<AuctionBid>().Where(auctionBid => auctionBid.AuctionBidProp)
```

Now I would like to do a case on type of subclass

```cs
auctions.Where(auction => 
    (auction is AuctionBid) && ((AuctionBid) auction).Prop == 1 
    || (auction is AuctionBuy) && ((AuctionBuy) auction).Prop == 1)
```

Is there the way to do it?

Of course line above gives an error: LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: Is reading all (or some) auctions into memory and then using LINQ a viable option in your case?

Comment: I would rather have proper paging on database side. For now I have added additional mapped field same as discriminator and moved needed property to base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only option I see is to query the sub types separately and concatenate the results:

```
auctions.OfType<AuctionBid>()
        .Where(auctionBid => auctionBid.AuctionBidProp == 1)
        .Cast<AuctionBase>
        .Concat(auctions.OfType<AuctionBuy>()
                        .Where(auctionBuy => auctionBuy.AuctionBidProp == 1)
               )
        .OrderBy(ab => ab.Prop1)
        .Skip(pages * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize)
```

This will generate a `UNION ALL` query. Not the most efficient approach when compared to hand-crafted SQL, but maybe acceptable (you'll have to try).

Comment: Maybe a sproc that handles paging would be viable since as you pointed out the generated query might lack performance.

Comment: Apparently that is the best way to do it and stay with EF Linq syntax.