# Switch in EF Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, switch-statement

i need some help with Linq in EF. I have a customer table with a column named "CustomerKind" of Type EKind, which is an Enum of three kinds (Kind1, Kind2, Kind3).

I also have additional tables, lets say "Kind1Details", "Kind2Details" and "Kind3Details". Every of this details table holds a special Name (column Name).

Now i want to grap information with an EF Linq statement. If CustomerKind is Kind1, i want the name of table Kind1Details, if it is Kind2 of Kind2Details and Kind3 of Kind3Details. So actually i need a switch in the select new clause. like this:

```
            var customerList=from customer in context.Customer
                             select new
                             {
                                 Id=customer.Id, 
                                 Kind=customer.CustomerKind, 
                                 if(Kind==EKind.Kind1)
                                    Name=customer.Kind1.Name
                                  if (Kind == EKind.Kind2)
                                    Name = customer.Kind2.Name
                                 if (Kind == EKind.Kind3)
                                    Name = customer.Kind3.Name
                            }
```

I can load all data and iterate again through it after the query, but maybe there is a better way.

Finally i got it, thank you guys. here is my working solution:

```
var customerList = from customer in context.Customer
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = customer.Id,
                        Kind = customer.CustomerKind,
                        Name1 = (Kind == EKind.Kind1) ? customer.Kind1.Name : null,
                        Name2 = (Kind == EKind.Kind2) ? customer.Kind2.Name : null,
                        Name3 = (Kind == EKind.Kind3) ? customer.Kind3.Name : null,

                        Age1 = (Kind == EKind.Kind1) ? customer.Kind1.Age : 0,
                        Age2 = (Kind == EKind.Kind2) ? customer.Kind2.Age : 0,
                        Age3 = (Kind == EKind.Kind3) ? customer.Kind3.Age : 0,

                    };

return customerList.Select(r => new CustomerOV
{
    Age = r.Age1 + r.Age2 + r.Age3,
    Name = r.Name1 ?? r.Name2 ?? r.Name3,
}).ToList();
```

Nico

Comment: I believe the word you are looking for is [Discriminator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333297/entity-framework-do-case-on-discriminator)

Comment: Please don't edit your question with your answer. If your solution is significantly different than one of the provided answers, please submit your own answer and accept it. However, if one of the provided answers is valid, please accept that. Regardless, don't put an answer in your question.

Comment: hey krillgar, i wanted to submit my answer and accept it, but i got a stupid error, that my account is banned from answering questions (maybe i'm too bad for answering, or my english sucks, i dont know). I only can get out of the ban by positive votes of my answers... But how can answers be voted, if i cant answer? With this edit i got the chance that people can read my accepted answer.

Comment: I fixed the incorrect syntax in my answer, you don't need to do all you are doing in yours.

Answer (score 3):

Tried to make a comment on the other answer, but it was too long. The `?:` operator produces the right hand side of an assignment, so the correct way to use it would be:

```
var customerList = from customer in context.Customer
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = customer.Id,
                        Kind = customer.CustomerKind,
                        Name = (Kind == EKind.Kind1)
                            ? customer.Kind1.Name
                            : (Kind == EKind.Kind2)
                                ? customer.Kind2.Name
                                : (Kind == EKind.Kind3)
                                    ? customer.Kind3.Name
                                    : "Unknown Kind"
                    };
```

Comment: thanks rufus, this looks not nice, but it is working. I have made it a little bit more clear and answered my own question in my initialize post. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
var customerList = from customer in context.Customer
                         select new {
                             Id=customer.Id, 
                             Kind=customer.CustomerKind, 
                             Name = (Kind == EKind.Kind1) ? customer.Kind1.Name :
                                    (Kind == EKind.Kind2) ? customer.Kind2.Name :
                                    (Kind == EKind.Kind3) ? customer.Kind3.Name : "bad kind",
                             Age = (Kind == EKind.Kind1) ? customer.Kind1.Age :
                                   (Kind == EKind.Kind2) ? customer.Kind2.Age :
                                   (Kind == EKind.Kind3) ? customer.Kind3.Age : 0
                        };
```

Comment: This results in an compiler error CS0746
Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.
An anonymous type must be declared with a member assignment, simple name, or member access.